# Disable toggle based on a condition

Tags: jquery

I am trying to disable a toggle function based on the value of the input field. Below is the markup

```
<ul>
  <li><input type="text" class="search" placeholder="Search..." id="search"></li>
  <li><button type="submit" id="search-submit"><span></span></button></li>
</ul>
```

Initially the search input will have width set to 0. On clicking the submit button, a toggle class is added which will animate the width of the text input. If there's any value in the text input, on clicking the submit button it should redirect to a page but it shouldn't toggle. I tried the below javascript but somehow not able to disable the toggle.

```
$('.sm-search button').click(function () {
 $('.search').toggleClass('search-expand');
});
$('.search').on('change keyup paste', function () {
 if ($(this).val() != "") {
  $('.sm-search button').click(function () {
   window.location.href = "/some-url";
   $('.search').addClass('search-expand');
  });
 } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

your jQuery-selectors don't match your HTML-classes, but that's probably just a problem right here.

What's happening here is:

you add multiple JS-listener to your button, which are all executed. If you want your code, you have to remove the initial "click"-listener.

try:

```
$('.sm-search button').click(function () {
 $('.search').toggleClass('search-expand');
});
$('.search').on('change keyup paste', function () {
 if ($(this).val() != "") {
  $('.sm-search button').off('click').click(function () {
   window.location.href = "/some-url";
   $('.search').addClass('search-expand'); // this shouldn't be necessary anymore, since you do not toggle the class anymore
  });
 } else {
    $('.sm-search button').off('click').on('click', function () {
      $('.search').toggleClass('search-expand');
    });
 }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. But this still doesn't work when user inputs the value, delete the value and then click the button. If the input value is empty it should simply toggle. User may input values and may delete after entering the value as well.

Comment: I updated my answer (if has now an else-block). try this :)